# phonegap android application not responding

Tags: android, cordova, timeout, extract, freeze

my phonegap application is not responding / timout window focus issues /appwindowtoken etc, when I use this code. basically, the app loads, but I have black screen and everything freezes.

Maybe I am processing to  much in the main activity. I am trying to extract a file.

how do I fix this.

code appreciated.

thanks in advance,

Jeremy

```
    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
    import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.util.Log;

    import org.apache.cordova.*;

    public class tester extends DroidGap
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
            super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
            //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")
            File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath()+"/mysoundboard/com.test.dsoundfxboard/1.dat");
            if(! file.exists())        
            {


            boolean test = noiser.extractZip(extStore.getAbsolutePath()+"/mysoundboard/mydsoundfxboard.zip", extStore.getAbsolutePath()+"/mysoundboard/com.test.dsoundfxboard/");
            FileOutputStream fOut = null;
            OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
            if(test == true)
            {
                try {
                fOut openFileOutput(extStore.getAbsolutePath()+"/mysoundboard/com.test.dsoundfxboard/1.dat",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 

                osw.write('1');
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                osw.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                osw.close();
                fOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
            }
            }
        }



        private static boolean extractZip(String pathOfZip,String pathToExtract)
        {


               int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
               int size;
               byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];


               try {
                   File f = new File(pathToExtract);
                   if(!f.isDirectory()) {
                       f.mkdirs();
                   }
                   ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(pathOfZip), BUFFER_SIZE));
                   try {
                       ZipEntry ze = null;
                       while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                           String path = pathToExtract  +"/"+ ze.getName();

                           if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                               File unzipFile = new File(path);
                               if(!unzipFile.isDirectory()) {
                                   unzipFile.mkdirs();
                               }
                           }
                           else {
                               FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path, false);
                               BufferedOutputStream fout = new BufferedOutputStream(out, BUFFER_SIZE);
                               try {
                                   while ( (size = zin.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1 ) {
                                       fout.write(buffer, 0, size);
                                   }

                                   zin.closeEntry();
                               }catch (Exception e) {
                                   Log.e("Exception", "Unzip exception 1:" + e.toString());
                               }
                               finally {
                                   fout.flush();
                                   fout.close();
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }catch (Exception e) {
                       Log.e("Exception", "Unzip exception2 :" + e.toString());
                   }
                   finally {
                       zin.close();
                   }
                   return true;
               }
               catch (Exception e) {
                   Log.e("Exception", "Unzip exception :" + e.toString());
               }
               return false;

           }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is blocking the UI Thread, use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to extract the zipped files in a separate thread.